# How to move from first screen(just with button to tabbed activity) to second screen(tab activity) in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**I have three .js files in my react native project:**

- App.js
- LoginPage.js
- RootNavigation.js

My launcher screen is **LoginPage.js**  now i need to go to **Rootnavigation.js** .

**RootNavigation.js** has import **MainTabnavigator.js**

**App.js:**

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font } from 'expo';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import RootNavigation from './navigation/RootNavigation';
import LoginPage from './screens/LoginPage';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';



export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };


  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <RootNavigation />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        require('./assets/images/robot-prod.png'),
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
        ...Ionicons.font,
        // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
        // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
        'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
      }),
    ]);
  };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    // reporting service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
export default justsms = createStackNavigator(
{

 First: { screen: LoginPage },

 Second: { screen: App }

});
```

**LoginPage.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image,  Platform,  ScrollView,  StyleSheet,  Text,  TouchableOpacity,  View, Button} from 'react-native';
export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions={
    title:'Login Page'
  };
  NavigateActivityFunction = () =>
  {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Second');

  }
  render(){
    return(<View style={styles.container}>
     <Button title='Tab Activity' onPress={this.NavigateActivityFunction}/>
</View>
);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent:'center'

  }
});
```

RootNavigation.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Notifications } from 'expo';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
import registerForPushNotificationsAsync from '../api/registerForPushNotificationsAsync';

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
});

export default class RootNavigation extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._notificationSubscription = this._registerForPushNotifications();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._notificationSubscription && this._notificationSubscription.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return <AppNavigator />;
  }

  _registerForPushNotifications() {
    // Send our push token over to our backend so we can receive notifications
    // You can comment the following line out if you want to stop receiving
    // a notification every time you open the app. Check out the source
    // for this function in api/registerForPushNotificationsAsync.js
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

    // Watch for incoming notifications
    this._notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(this._handleNotification);
  }

  _handleNotification = ({ origin, data }) => {
    console.log(`Push notification ${origin} with data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  };
}
```

**MainTabNavigator.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Links',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-link${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-link'}
    />
  ),
};

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-options'}
    />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack,
});
```

Here when i click on button in **LoginPage.js** it should go to tab activity . I tried **importing** **MainTabNavigator.js** in **App.js** but when i click on button nothing is happening. I would be glad if someone Help me in this issue.